# can linearly independent functions with zero wronskian be solutions to homogenous differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have this doubt since long time. I came across this statement in a book that two solutions to a linear second order homogenous equation are linearly dependent on an interval if and only if their wronskian is zero on that interval.

$x^3$ and $x^2|x|$ are linearly independent on $[-1,1]$ but they have $0$ wronskian. So would that mean they cannot be fundamental solutions to same second order linear differential equation defined on $[-1,1]$? is there any way to prove they cannot be solutions? but if they are solutions, would'nt that contradict the statement?

Answer (score 1):

This example is dealt with in Birkhoff and Rota's *Ordinary Differential
Equations*. They observe that these two functions satisfy both $xu'=3u$
and $3xu''-2u'=0$.

They prove that this phenomenon doesn't occur for equations $u''+p(x)u'+q(x)=0$, $p$, $q$ continuous.

Comment: thank you. will non homogenity of the equation make it possible for those functions to be solutions?

Comment: Seems like both $x^3, x^2|x|$ satisfy the DE $xu'' - 2u' = 0$?